# MySQL and server load. 1 table vs multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I am creating a link shortening website were the user inputs a link, and the link will be shortened. The links will be stored in database tables.

What would be the most suitable solution in terms of server load? To store all the links in one table? or to store the links in individual user tables (1 table per user)?

The table's will be accessed continuously. If I use 1 table, will the server slow down once the table starts filling up with links and data?

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to solve this in terms of scalability but my recommendation is start small, just define a single table to store everything and go from there.

You can always scale later.